# Sligthly Different Word Frequency after Text Tokenization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, plot, nlp

I'm doing some work on NLP and I was doing some tasks of tokenization and text preprocessing while found this:

Funtion using to plot word frequency:

```
def len_distribution(X):
    x = [len(n) for n in X]

    plt.hist(x, bins=len(x))
    plt.xlabel('Number of words')
    plt.ylabel('Number of texts')
    plt.title('Distribution of text length on dataset')
    plt.show()
```

Word frequency **before** tokenization (plain text):

```
len_distribution([x.split() for x in X])
```

[image]

Word frequency **after** tokenization (sequences):

```
tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
X_encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)
len_distribution(X_encoded)
```

[image]

Basically I thought both plots should be **exaclty** the same, shouldn't them? Because words are just being changed by numbers but the frequency of each number must be the same as before, why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the first case, you use `split()` to tokenize your words, which splits by space between words: `'This sentence is a sentence.'` results in the tokens `['This', 'sentence', 'is' 'a', 'sentence.']`.
But the tokenizer from keras removes punctuation, as described [here](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/text/):

> By default, all punctuation is removed, turning the texts into space-separated sequences of words (words maybe include the ' character). These sequences are then split into lists of tokens. They will then be indexed or vectorized.

So the tokens from keras-tokenizer would look like this: `['This', 'sentence', 'is' 'a', 'sentence']`(did you notice the missing dot in the end?). As you can see, the count of the token 'sentence' is different compared to the first method, being two in the second case.

I guess this is at least one reason why the two diagrams are not the same.